# Android Multi-row summation: Request for code shortening

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, optimization, nested-if

I have a table with fifteen rows. Each row have three columns and a total column. I want to get the total per row, the grand total, and the overall average.

The user may not enter data for all rows, and the user may skip a row.

So the code checks if the user have entered data in one of three fields of each row.

1. If the row is blank, ignore it.
2. If some of the fields are filled-up, tell the user to fill up the rest of the row.
3. If all the fields in a row is filled up, sum all its fields and increment the divider.

I have only pasted the codes for Rows 1 & 2 for brevity, but it shows the gist of what I'm trying to achieve:

The code:

```
var a1 = 0
var a2 = 0
var total = 0
var divider = 0


// Row 1
if (b1p1.text.isNotEmpty() or b2p1.text.isNotEmpty() or b3p1.text.isNotEmpty()) {
    var y = 0
    listOf(b1p1, b2p1, b3p1).forEach {
        if (it.text.isEmpty()) {
            it.error = "Fill up empty fields!"
            y = 1
        }
    }

    if (y == 0) {
        divider++
        listOf(b1p1, b2p1, b3p1).forEach {
            a1 += it.text.toString().toInt()
        }
        total1.text = a1.toString()
        total += a1
        e2 = 1
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

// Row 2
if (b1p2.text.isNotEmpty() or b2p2.text.isNotEmpty() or b3p2.text.isNotEmpty()) {
    var y = 0
    listOf(b1p2, b2p2, b3p2).forEach {
        if (it.text.isEmpty()) {
            it.error = "Fill up empty fields!"
            y = 1
        }
    }

    if (y == 0) {
        divider++
        listOf(b1p2, b2p2, b3p2).forEach {
            a2 += it.text.toString().toInt()
        }
        total2.text = a2.toString()
        total += a2
    } else {

        Toast.makeText(activity, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

if (e2 == 1) {

    grandTotalTextView.text = total.toString()

    average = total.toDouble()/divider

    val decimalFormatter = DecimalFormat("#,###.##")

    averageTextView.text = decimalFormatter.format(average).toString()

    cyeSingleton.anct3b = decimalFormatter.format(average).toString()

} else {

    Toast.makeText(activity, "Error 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

The table:

[image]

This is the best I could come up with. Should there be no other suggestion, I will settle for this.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: Thanks to ** https://stackoverflow.com/users/3736955/jemshit-iskenderov

```
data class TotalResult(val divider:Int, val allTotal:Int, val showError:Boolean)

private fun calculateTotalResult(allTextViews:List<List<TextView>>, totalTextViews:List<TextView>): TotalResult {
    var divider = 0
    var allTotal = 0
    var showError=false

    allTextViews.forEachIndexed{index, rowTextViews->
        val rowResult = calculateRowResult(rowTextViews as List<EditText>, totalTextViews[index])
        if(!rowResult.ignoreRow){
            if(rowResult.allFieldsFilled){
                divider+=1
                allTotal+=rowResult.rowTotal
            }else{
                showError = true
            }
        }
    }

    Toast.makeText(
        activity,
        "$divider, $allTotal, $showError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        .show()

    return TotalResult(divider, allTotal, showError)

}

data class RowResult(val ignoreRow:Boolean, val allFieldsFilled:Boolean, val rowTotal:Int)

private fun calculateRowResult(rowTextViews:List<EditText>, totalTextView:TextView): RowResult {
    val ignore = rowTextViews.filter{it.text.isBlank()}.count() == rowTextViews.size
    if(ignore)
        return RowResult(true, false, 0)

    var emptyFieldCount = 0
    var total = 0
    rowTextViews.forEach {textView ->
        if (textView.text.isEmpty()) {
            textView.error = "Fill up empty fields!"
            emptyFieldCount +=1
        }else{
            val fieldValue:Int? = textView.text.toString().toIntOrNull() // or toIntOrElse{0}
            if(fieldValue!=null) total+=fieldValue
        }
    }

    if(emptyFieldCount==0)
        totalTextView.text = total.toString()

    return RowResult(false, emptyFieldCount==0, total)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fun main(){
  val totalResult = calculateTotalResult(
    allTextViews = listOf(
        listOf(t11,t12,t13),
        listOf(t21,t22,t23)
    ),
    totalTextViews = listOf(totalView1, totalView2)
  )

  // single Toast error
  if(totalResult.showError){
      // showToast(error)
  }

  // use totalResult.divider, totalResult.allTotal
}

data class TotalResult(val divider:Int, val allTotal:Int, val showError:Boolean)

fun calculateTotalResult(allTextViews:List<List<TextView>>, totalTextViews:List<TextView>){
  var divider = 0
  var allTotal = 0
  var showError=false

  allTextViews.forEachIndexed{index, rowTextViews->
      val rowResult = calculateRowResult(rowTextViews, totalTextViews[index])
      if(!rowResult.ignore){
        if(rowResult.allFieldsFilled){
            divider+=1
            allTotal+=rowResult.rowTotal
        }else{
            showError = true
        }
      }
  }

  return TotalResult(divider, allTotal, showError)
}

data class RowResult(val ignoreRow:Boolean, val allFieldsFilled:Boolean, val rowTotal:Int)

fun calculateRowResult(rowTextViews:List<TextView>, totalTextView:TextView): RowResult {
    val ignore = rowTextViews.filter{it.isBlank()}.count() == rowTextViews.size
    if(ignore)
      return RowResult(true, false, 0)

    var emptyFieldCount = 0
    var total = 0
    rowTextViews.forEach {textView ->
        if (textView.text.isEmpty()) {
            textView.error = "Fill up empty fields!"
            emptyFieldCount +=1
        }else{
            val fieldValue:Int? = textView.text.toString().toIntOrNull() // or toIntOrElse{0}
            if(fieldValue!=null) total+=fieldValue
        }
    }

    if(emptyFieldCount==0)
      totalTextView.text = total.toString()

    return RowResult(false, emptyFieldCount==0, total)
}
```

Extracted `calculateTotalResult()` and `calculateRowResult()` so multiple rows and columns do not need to repeat same code.

`calculateRowResult()` processes singlet row of TextViews. I had to iterate `rowTextViews` twice, one to calculate ignore, the other to show error on TextView if not ignore. We don't show Toast Error here yet.

`calculateTotalResult()` iterates through all rows and gets total result. We show only one Toast Error (if required) after this step.

Code is pseudo-code, not tested.

Comment: Wow, thanks mate! Sorry it took long to get back to you (was cooking Crispy Pata and had some hot oil splash on my face).

With some tweaks, I managed to adopt your code to my project.

If possible, could you make it class in Kotlin so it would be reusable to other fragments?

You've been a great help.

Thanks!

Comment: @KellinStrook just put in SomeCalculator.kt file without any class declaration and use functions anywhere